# Sitemesh 3. Output all body tag attributes to the layout

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, sitemesh

I have a page with:

```
<body class="auth_loginForm" controller="auth" action="loginForm" >
```

and a sitemesh layout with body:

```
 <body iamalayout="true" >
    <sitemesh:write property='body'/>
 </body>
```

Is there a way to make the attributes of the body appear on the final page?

That is the final body tag would look like:

```
<body iamalayout="true" class="auth_loginForm" controller="auth" action="loginForm" >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting your layout body tag like this:

```
<body iamalayout="true" <decorator:getProperty property="body.class" /> <decorator:getProperty property="body.controller" /> <decorator:getProperty property="body.action" /> >
```

or if it's not working right try to append writeEntireProperty="true" for each decorator:getProperty tag, like

```
 <decorator:getProperty property="body.class" writeEntireProperty="true" />
```

Hope it helps.

http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh/Tag+References